# NSCoding with custom sub Objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nscoding

I have one costum object which has a reference to another custom object.
How do I encode the custom object within the one custom object in my `- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder` method?

Lets say name is a string an cObj is another custom obj:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
   [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
   [encoder encodeObject:self.cObj forKey:@"cObj"];
   }
```

Does this will call `- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder` in my other custom object?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cObj needs to support `<NSCoding>`, so yes.